# Android Studio / Flutter / Firebase - Unable to get gradle model to access current dependencies

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to setup Tools - Firebase in Android Studio for my Flutter project, but I am getting this error message in my Android Studio log:

```
2023-06-22 14:23:19,047 [ 286417]   WARN - #c.g.s.f.a.d.DependencyStateManager - Unable to get gradle model to access current dependencies
2023-06-22 14:23:19,279 [ 286649]   INFO - #c.g.s.f.a.d.DependencyStateManager - did not find plugin: com.google.gms.google-services
```

When I hit on the Connect to Firebase button , I am also getting the error message

```
2023-06-22 14:23:24,544 [ 291914]   WARN - #c.i.o.e.m.t.ExternalSystemTaskId - No project found for RESOLVE_PROJECT:1
2023-06-22 14:23:24,563 [ 291933]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - no accessors for com.android.tools.idea.layoutinspector.settings.LayoutInspectorSettings
```

"Could not find the Android Application module. Only Android Application Modules can be connected to Firebase online projects. Create a new Android Application Module or create/import a different Android Studio project." I notice tons of unanswered questions for this problem [Firebase connecting problem. "Could not find the Android Application module. Only Android Application Modules can be connected to Firebase online"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73486052/firebase-connecting-problem-could-not-find-the-android-application-module-onl)
[firebase auth with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359292/firebase-auth-with-flutter)
etc

My gradle setup is regular vanilla Flutter app project. I do have the Android module setup.

I also noticed in a related question [Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39892622/plugin-with-id-com-google-gms-google-services-not-found) thta Flutter vanilla projects dont add the plugins section in the root and projet gradle files, eg this one is missing:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' 
    id 'com.android.library'
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}
```

[image]